# How can create binary in Xcode 4.0

Tags: ios4, xcode4

How can create binary in Xcode 4.0?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Binary what?

Comment: Who would add *that* to his favorite questions ???

Comment: I want to find .app file

Comment: @DarkDust : well, I add it :) It's somewhat rather "difficult" for newbie like us :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open project. Find folder with name Product. Right click and select "open with finder".

Comment: I rather use the Archive process for this @fasttracks. Isn't so?

Answer (score 3):

You press the "Build and run" button, or you select "Build" (or "Build and run" if you also want to run your app afterwards) from the "Build" menu.

The binary executable will be written to the folder specified in your project settings. By default, this is /build/debug and /build/release, depending on whether you selected a release or debug build.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Can you be a bit more precise?

Answer (score 1):

From project, **select product**, then select the **.app file**.

**Right click on it** and select **show in Finder**.

From Finder compress it and finally upload the compressed file to iTunes connect.